# How to install Pillow 7.0.0 on Pycharm running Python 3.8?

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to use Django and displaying images from a Sql db, following this [LinkedIn Learning tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/building-a-personal-portfolio-with-django/creating-the-models-in-django?u=2209922).

In the process of running manage.py to run my django development server, I face an issue where I have to have pillow installed.

This process has so far proven tedious and here are the things I've tried:

1. Ran the "simple" `python -m pip Pillow`, `python -m pip Pillow --upgrade` in the PyCharm terminal, then get:

```
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

2. (Pycharm Ultimate, which I have): Running the WSL environment as provided in the [release notes](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/10/pycharm-2018-3-eap-7/). This *should* to work as I have the required pre-reqs installed in WSL. However, my computer runs the dreaded ["skeletons" process](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/10/pycharm-2018-3-eap-7/) for quite a long time, and I don't see it ending anytime soon.
3. Attempting to install from the PyCharm GUI also fails in the same way as 1.
4. Attempting to install the following binaries from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow which is referenced in some other answers for this topic gives me this error when installing via `pip install <wheel name here>`:

`Pillow-7.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

**pip3 doesn't work either. Mentioning although in my PyCharm virtualenv they both point to the same python interpreter. At first glance...

**My main ask is** - has anyone been able to install pillow 7.0.0 on Windows 10, for a PyCharm virtualenv? And, if so, how have you done it? So I can get back to learning! Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Updated steps taken in (1). Sorry about that

Comment: Pillow 7.0 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/7.0.0/#files) all possible wheels for many Python versions and platforms. Try `pip install -vvv Pillow` to understand why `pip` doesn't use one of them.

Comment: When I ran 'pip install -vvv' most of the available sources were incompatible. However, it did help me to realize that I was running Python 3.8 (32 bit) on 64 bit windows. I thought that was the main issue (and that setup.py was compiling for this "edge case" install but even using 64 bit python results in no luck.

Comment: I see wheels for both 32- and 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I found a similar issue on github. It's for 6.2.1, not 7.0.0. but in case anyone else stumbles upon this question, I hope it helps. I've not been able to use pillow 7 on my pycharm install. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4158